# How to Use Toastr Alerts in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, toastr

Is there any way to use Toastr Alerts in PHP Application? I would like to show the Success & Error Messages using Toastr Notifications. Is there any Libraries available for php ?

javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   toastr.info('User Registered..!');
</script>
```

how to archive this form only using php?

Comment: What have you tried? Are there any libraries you have tried?

Comment: I didn't try any libraries.

Comment: also you can use sweet alerts instead of toasts . simply google sweet alerts .

Comment: I don't see why `PHP` is relevant here. And "I didn't use any libraries" doesn't match with your code, which uses `toastr`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you have to add Toastr CSS,JS & jquery inside you header.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/js/toastr.js"></script>
```

Then you can use Toastr alerts wherever you want. You can use below method for PHP Applications.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">toastr.success('Have Fun')</script>';
```

For More Information : https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Comment: It works Thanks. I tried many ways but not possible achieve that @AhamedSafnaj

Comment: Toastr Project seems to be abandoned